# supervisord running node as a service

Tags: javascript, node.js, supervisord

I am trying to run a node application as a service using supervisord.

If I go to /opt/uptime and run:

```
node app.js
```

My application starts in the foreground. As soon as I hit ctrl+c it dies.. As expected.

I have installed supervisor and have added this to the config:

```
[program:uptime]
command=/usr/local/bin/node app.js
directory=/opt/uptime/
```

I can start supervisor successfully but if I do supervisorctl status I get:

```
uptime         BACKOFF    Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Here are the log files:

/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log

```
2013-04-25 09:37:10,854 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2013-04-25 09:37:10,866 INFO /var/tmp/supervisor.sock:Medusa (V1.1.1.1) started at Thu Apr 25 09:37:10 2013
Hostname: <unix domain socket>
Port:/var/tmp/supervisor.sock
2013-04-25 09:37:10,914 CRIT Running without any HTTP authentication checking
2013-04-25 09:37:10,915 INFO daemonizing the process
2013-04-25 09:37:10,917 INFO supervisord started with pid 28099
2013-04-25 09:37:10,918 INFO spawned: 'uptime' with pid 28101
2013-04-25 09:37:11,015 INFO exited: uptime (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-04-25 09:37:11,016 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-04-25 09:37:12,019 INFO spawned: 'uptime' with pid 28103
2013-04-25 09:37:12,082 INFO exited: uptime (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-04-25 09:37:12,082 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-04-25 09:37:14,086 INFO spawned: 'uptime' with pid 28105
2013-04-25 09:37:14,153 INFO exited: uptime (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-04-25 09:37:14,154 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-04-25 09:37:17,157 INFO spawned: 'uptime' with pid 28107
2013-04-25 09:37:17,220 INFO exited: uptime (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-04-25 09:37:17,220 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-04-25 09:37:18,221 INFO gave up: uptime entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2013-04-25 09:37:20,372 INFO localhost:0 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:37:20 -0600] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 254
2013-04-25 09:37:20,374 INFO localhost:0 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:37:20 -0600] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 1236
```

Comment: And what does the process log say?

Comment: I edited the original question with the logs... Should be easier to read.

Comment: do you have /var/log/supervisord/uptime-stderr-XXXX.log? What does it say?

Comment: I do not have that file.

Comment: Add `redirect_stderr=true` to the program, and then tail it using `supervisorctl tail uptime`. Those logs will contain the actual error output of your node process.

Comment: did you see this issue? it looks similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151908/dotcloud-nodejs-supervisord-conf-not-working

Answer (score 6):

If i understand correctly, the code should look like this:

If directory = /usr/local/bin/ :

```
[program:uptime]
directory = /usr/local/bin/
command = node app.js
```

If directory = /opt/uptime/ :

```
[program:uptime]
directory = /opt/uptime/
command = node app.js
```